# cannot open file downloaded using download manager API inside android webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, wkwebview, download-manager

I am downloading pdf files inside web view in android studio. That's going well. I am successfully downloading a pdf file with the .pdf extension but when I **click on the file** see a toast message **something went wrong can't open this file**
Here is my code

```
 binding?.webView?.setDownloadListener { url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength ->
            val pdfUrl:String = url.trim().replace("blob:","")
            Log.e(TAG, "loadWAWeb:  $pdfUrl")
            if (storagePermission()) {
//                binding?.webView?.loadUrl(JavaScriptInterface.getBase64StringFromBlobUrl(url,mimetype))
                val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(pdfUrl))
                request.setMimeType(mimetype)
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...")
                val fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(pdfUrl, contentDisposition, mimetype)
                request.setTitle(fileName)

                Log.e(TAG, "loadWAWeb:  $fileName" )
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)

                val dm = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
                dm.enqueue(request)

            }

        }
```

this is a pdf file which is good in format but I don't know where is the issue.

[image]

but when I try to open this file. This issue that I am facing.

[image]

Comment: Where is it that you see the file and can click on it?

Comment: after downloading, I can see it in the **file manager download folder**. When I clicked on the file it tried to open and then showed a message **something went wrong can't open this file**.

Comment: Which file manager? And who said that ? The manager or the choosen pdf reader? Have you checked the file size of the downloaded file?

Comment: Please see the above question I update my question with more explanation

Comment: Nice pictures. But you forgot to tell us which app gave you the message that it could not open the file. Also you did not tell us if file sizes of original and downloaded file are equal.

Comment: no actual file size is 627kb but the downloaded file size is 251kb

Answer (score 0):

I Don't see that have a problem, maybe the pdf file just corrupted. Test in another PDF File or just update your Android Studio. in my case before i am implement Fast Android Networking the file sometimes corrupted, but after i am implement Fast Android Networking the file is not corrupted.

in Gradle, paste this

```
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
```

and add Internet Permission on Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Then initialize it in onCreate() Method of application class

```
AndroidNetworking.initialize(getApplicationContext());
```

i think my explanation is not that good, you can see at https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

im sorry if this not make you problem solved, but based on my case it solved

Comment: Please see my code and tell me here how to use this library.

Answer (score 0):

Continuously my downloaded file was **corrupting** I handled this as:

**JavaScriptInterface.kt**

```
package com.hamza.hiwhatsappweb.utils

import android.R
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.os.Handler
import android.util.Base64
import android.util.Log
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException


class JavaScriptInterface(private val context: Context) {
    @JavascriptInterface
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun getBase64FromBlobData(base64Data: String) {
        Log.e("mimeType", "getBase64FromBlobData:  $mimTp")
        convertBase64StringToPdfAndStoreIt(base64Data)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun convertBase64StringToPdfAndStoreIt(base64PDf: String) {
        Log.e("BASE 64", base64PDf)
        val notificationId = 1
        val dwldsPath = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/$fileName")
        val pdfAsBytes =
            Base64.decode(base64PDf.replaceFirst("^data:$mimTp;base64,".toRegex(), ""), 0)
        val os = FileOutputStream(dwldsPath, false)
        os.write(pdfAsBytes)
        os.flush()
        if (dwldsPath.exists()) {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
            val apkURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", dwldsPath)
            intent.setDataAndType(apkURI, mimTp)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            val pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
            val CHANNEL_ID = "MYCHANNEL"
            val notificationManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val notificationChannel =
                    NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                val notification = Notification.Builder(
                    context, CHANNEL_ID
                )
                    .setContentText(fileName)
                    .setContentTitle("File downloaded")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sym_action_chat)
                    .build()
                if (notificationManager != null) {
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
                    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
                }
            } else {
                val b = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sym_action_chat) //.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentTitle("MY TITLE")
                    .setContentText("MY TEXT CONTENT")
                if (notificationManager != null) {
                    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, b.build())
                    val h = Handler()
                    val delayInMilliseconds: Long = 1000
                    h.postDelayed({ notificationManager.cancel(notificationId) }, delayInMilliseconds)
                }
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "PDF FILE DOWNLOADED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    companion object {
        var mimTp:String = ""
        var fileName:String = ""
        fun getBase64StringFromBlobUrl(blobUrl: String, mimeType: String,fileName:String): String {
            mimTp = mimeType
            this.fileName = fileName
            return if (blobUrl.startsWith("blob")) {
                "javascript: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
                        "xhr.open('GET', '" + blobUrl + "', true);" +
                        "xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','$mimeType');" +
                        "xhr.responseType = 'blob';" +
                        "xhr.onload = function(e) {" +
                        "    if (this.status == 200) {" +
                        "        var blobPdf = this.response;" +
                        "        var reader = new FileReader();" +
                        "        reader.readAsDataURL(blobPdf);" +
                        "        reader.onloadend = function() {" +
                        "            base64data = reader.result;" +
                        "            Android.getBase64FromBlobData(base64data);" +
                        "        }" +
                        "    }" +
                        "};" +
                        "xhr.send();"
            } else "javascript: console.log('It is not a Blob URL');"
        }
    }
}
```

Set this property on Webview:

```
binding?.webView?.addJavascriptInterface(JavaScriptInterface(applicationContext), "Android")
        binding?.webView?.settings?.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON

        binding?.webView?.setDownloadListener { url, _, contentDisposition, mimetype, _ ->
//           downloadFiles(url, mimetype, contentDisposition)
            val pdfUrl: String? = url?.trim()?.replace("blob:", "")
            val fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(pdfUrl, contentDisposition, mimetype)

            binding?.webView?.loadUrl(JavaScriptInterface.getBase64StringFromBlobUrl(url,mimetype,fileName))

        }
```

**provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Paste this code under Application in AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```